# how to copy a row in a .csv file into a column in another .csv file in tcl ?

Tags: tcl

I wish to copy a specific row in a .csv file to a specific column in another .csv file using tcl.

What i've tried is to copy the row i wanted into a new .csv file and then copy this row manually into my .csv file. But I wish to automate all this and directly copy a row in the .csv into a column in an existing .csv file.

Here is what i tried:

```
package require csv

set fp [open "filenameSource.csv" r]    
set secondColumnData {}    
while {[gets $fp line]>=0} {    
    if {[llength $line]>0} {    
        lappend secondColumnData [lindex [split $line ","] 1]    
    }    
}    
close $fp     
puts $secondColumnData    
set filename "Destination.csv"    
set fileId [open $filename "w"]      
puts -nonewline $fileId $secondColumnData      
close
```

Is there a way to have a pointer at row x in the source file and copy it into a specific destination into the Destination file.

I am new to tcl. Please provide example.

Thanks, 
IEK

Comment: Just checking; you want a specific row (how to choose it?) to become a column? And is there anything else in the destination file before you start?

Comment: At a minimum, you'll want `[join $secondColumnData ,]` to write the row as comma-separated. If your data contains text fields, you might need some logic about adding and escaping double quotes.

Comment: @glennjackman I think that it's better to be using the csv package to load the data from the two files into matrices, which will make doing the transfer of data from a row of one to a column easy, and will give a trivial way to write the result out correctly oo.

Comment: @lelkalio, Can you provide more details? In your code snippet, you are hardcoding the 2nd column of the source file, and you are overwriting the destination file with a single line. You ask about retrieving a specific *row* and writing to a specific *column*. Please describe exactly what you need.

Comment: @DonalFellows : The file i want to copy the row from is a .csv file containing a matrix with nxm measurements values. In every column, i have 1 measurement mean value of the n rows. I want to get the row of the mean values for the m columns.  I want to copy this into a .csv file, that contains one column with the values of the mean. This destination file contains already a lot of other data inside it. I hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: @glennjackman good idea about the double quotes. I will use it when i arrive to this point. How do you copy them into matrices. Is it by using tcllib?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you'll need to learn as a newcomer to Tcl is that there's a lot of useful code in [Tcllib](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/toc.html), a suite of packages written by the Tcl community. In this case, the `csv` and `struct::matrix` packages make this task trivial (as I understand it), which is great because CSV files have some tricky aspects that aren't obvious.

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

# Read the source data
set srcMatrix [struct::matrix]
set f [open "filenameSource.csv" r]
csv::read2matrix $f $srcMatrix
close $f

# Read the destination data so we can UPDATE it
set dstMatrix [struct::matrix]
set f [open "Destination.csv" r+]
csv::read2matrix $f $dstMatrix
# Leaving the file open; we're going to rewrite it…

# Do the copying operation; I assume you know which row and column to copy from/to
$dstMatrix set column 2 [$srcMatrix get row 34]

# Write back
chan seek $f 0
csv::writematrix $f $dstMatrix
chan truncate $f;  # Make sure there's no junk left if the file shortened
close $f
```